# PhpStorm - export deployment DATA

Tags: ide, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm going to reinstall Windows and I have a lot of deployment projects, SSH connections, saved passwords in my PhpStorm.

How to export all this data?

Comment: Preserve you config folder: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs. Also check https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/sharing-your-ide-settings.html#import-export-settings and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/reference-ide-settings-password-safe.html. P.S. Project specific settings are stored together with the project (.idea subfolder)

Comment: It's just a matter of saving one folder (`config`) for Windows/Linux (Mac OS may require few folders as plugins are stored separately). You may need to set Master Password for Keepass DB (where IDE stores passwords) so IDE will be able to read it on new machine/installation. AFAIK, if not set then that DB access is controlled by using "random" machine-specific key/password that will not be the same in new Windows install (check the links in my prev comment).